# Importing module using absolute path in python

Tags: python, package, python-import, importerror, init

I have a project with the following structure:

```
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── make_dataset.py
│   ├── models
│       ├── __init__.py
        └── train_model.py
```

***setup.py*** file:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="src",
    packages=find_packages(),
    version='0.1.0',
    description='ciao',
    author='Guglielmo Cerri',
    license='',
    package_dir={"": str("src")},
)
```

***make_dataset.py*** file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def hello():
    print("hi")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

***train_model.py*** file:

```
from data.make_dataset import hello


def main():
    hello()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I run `python train_model.py` inside `src/models` folder I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_model.py", line 1, in <module>
    from data.make_dataset import prova
ImportError: No module named data.make_dataset
```

How can I import the file make_dataset withe the absolute path using `from data.make_dataset import hello` ?. I do not want to run some installations with the setup.py, I just want to do the import just using the **init**.py files, it is possible?

Comment: Make sure `src` is on the sys path and it should work.

Comment: @Peter can you explain better? You mean  ```import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/src')```

Comment: Yeah, your `sys.path` is where python looks for modules, if you want to find the `data` module from the other one then you'll need to add it to the path. Alternatively, have a file like `src/run_training.py` that imports `data.make_dataset` and `models.train_model` and runs the code there, I think that would work. Basically absolute imports are a bit of a pain to run from _inside_ the module, but work great from outside.